# how to run command in Dart correctly?

Tags: flutter, dart

That's my code. I want to use Process.run to open a command to do something, like git clone or flutter build.

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  print('build start');
  // var res = await Process.run('git clone xxxx', []);
  var res = await Process.run('flutter build windows --dart-define=RunEnv=dist', []);
  print(res);
  print('build end');
}
```

But it failed.

```
Unhandled exception:
ProcessException: 系统找不到指定的文件。

  Command: flutter
```

Dart Process can't read global command variable like flutter or git? In nodejs is easy to do that. What should I do?

Comment: For git specific commands, you could also use https://pub.dev/packages/rw_git which is a git wrapper written in dart. It offers all/most of the common operations that someone would like to execute via git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntaxis is not right. All parameters have to supplied as a list of string, rewrite it to:

```
  final ProcessResult res = await Process.run(
    'flutter',
    <String>[
      'build',
      'windows',
      '--dart-define=RunEnv=dist'
    ],
  );
```

[Edit] Link to documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Process/run.html [/edit]

Comment: It failed. 
```
Unhandled exception:
ProcessException: 系统找不到指定的文件。

  Command: flutter build --dart-define=RunEnv=dist

```

Comment: I found that only flutter failed. Other like node, git is ok.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to add 'windows' to the parameter list. I have addid it to the answer. We use this all the time, so it should be working. Are you sure you are using it fromt he right directory? You can specify a parameter workingDirectory to be sure it's running from the correct dir.

Comment: Oh and is flutter added to your path? Can you run "flutter doctor" from any directory?

Comment: Hello, you can use formatting on StackOverflow to make your answer easier to read. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more